# Trouble parsing string for url request

Tags: python, urllib3

Prompt: I am attempting to access the SEC EDGAR Database to extract specific company files. I'm having trouble with my urllib.request.request(). Currently I need to access the source code of the site. After that I would parse with re for the body paragraphs

```
**import re
import urllib.request as request
import urllib.parse as parse
import pandas
import csv
'''
WE ARE finding & parsing information to find https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1018724/0001018724-20-000030.txt
'''
frm_type = input('Enter the file type (e.g. 10-k, 8-q): ')
year = input('Enter fiscal year(4 digit number): ')
quarter = input('Enter quarter (NOTE. Must be in format QTX, with x being 1-4): ')
CIK = input('Enter CIK (company identifier): ')
def find_sec_filings(cik, year, quarter, filetype):
    quarter = quarter.upper()
    """sources relevant file from EDGAR Database."""
    lookup = 'edgar/data/'
    web = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/'
    direction = web + str(year) + '/' + str(quarter) + '/' + 'master.idx'
    try:
        idx = request.urlopen(direction)  
        for line in idx:
            if year in line and cik in line:
                for element in line.split('|'):
                    if lookup in element:
                        file_direction = str(element\[lookup:\])
                        return file_direction
     except:
         print("No file with the specifications were found")
#Path to 10-k
fd = find_sec_filings(CIK,year,quarter,frm_type)
print(fd)
url1 = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/'+ fd

ERROR MESSAGE:
No file with the specifications were found
None
File "C:\\Users\\trisy\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\classes\\SP_22_courses\\CS1110\\pye_files\\edgar.py", line 44, in \<module\>
url1 = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/'+ fd
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str\`
```

Answer (score 0):

That function

```
def find_sec_filings(cik, year, quarter, filetype):
    quarter = quarter.upper()
    """sources relevant file from EDGAR Database."""
    lookup = 'edgar/data/'
    web = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/'
    direction = web + str(year) + '/' + str(quarter) + '/' + 'master.idx'
    try:
        idx = request.urlopen(direction)  
        for line in idx:
            if year in line and cik in line:
                for element in line.split('|'):
                    if lookup in element:
                        file_direction = str(element\[lookup:\])
                        return file_direction
     except:
         print("No file with the specifications were found")
```

does not guarantee `return` of string or failure. In case `if lookup in element:` never holds true `return file_direction` will be never reached. When no `return` is reached in python function `None` is `return`ed by function. Therefore after

```
fd = find_sec_filings(CIK,year,quarter,frm_type)
```

`fd` might either be string or `None`, you must not carelessly concatenate it with string. You might end with `TypeError` otherwise. As side not using `except:` (known as *bare except*) is considered to be bad practice in `python`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback and sorry for sloppy code. Still new to coding

Answer (score 0):

**A simple fix for your problem**

```
def find_sec_filings(cik, year, quarter, filetype):
    quarter = quarter.upper()
    """sources relevant file from EDGAR Database."""
    lookup = 'edgar/data/'
    web = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/'
    direction = web + str(year) + '/' + str(quarter) + '/' + 'master.idx'
    try:
        idx = request.urlopen(direction)  
        for line in idx:
            if year in line and cik in line:
                for element in line.split('|'):
                    if lookup in element:
                        file_direction = str(element\[lookup:\])
                        return file_direction
     except:
         print("No file with the specifications were found")
     return ""
```

This ensure the function returns a string and not None